# WKWebView with Basic Authentication in Swift complete example

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have been trying to put together an example of a `WKWebView` with a site that authenticates with Basic Auth. I want to use swift if possible. The examples that use the challenge with

```
URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
```

This does not add `Base64` encryption to the header. Doesn't it need it?

Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: What tutorial? More code?

Comment: Yes there is no example application that does Basic Authentication that I have found that works. Looking for help.

Comment: I guess no one has anything to offer. I would consider with objective-c as well.